# (statistics) 2-way table normalization

Tags: r, matlab, statistics

I have a table like this.

```
    X  X2008 X2009 X2010 X2011 X2012 X2013 X2014 X2015
1  SU 103.27 105.2  99.7 106.7  96.7 108.4  88.7 73.67
2  BS 100.17 104.5  97.6 103.6  91.7 106.2  85.5 73.66
3  DG 101.00 102.5  98.9 101.1  91.2 106.2  80.9 75.67
4  IC  97.80 103.4  97.2 102.4  88.4 103.3  85.7 70.00
5  DJ 106.20 103.1  99.1  97.7  90.7 106.2  77.5 74.00
6  GJ  97.47 101.7  98.6 101.2  89.9 105.6  81.7 73.33
7  US  99.80 105.6  98.2   0.0  81.7 103.6  84.3 68.00
8  GG  98.13 105.7  98.6 103.7  92.2 105.2  85.9 73.66
9  GO  96.13 101.2  96.8 101.7  86.4 105.7  78.1 72.66
10 CB 104.20 105.2 101.5 100.3  88.3 106.2  78.8 72.00
11 CN 107.20  95.0  96.1  98.7  88.2 103.7  78.5 71.33
12 GB  98.87 102.0  95.3 100.2  87.2 104.2  78.5 70.33
13 GN  99.57 103.3  95.6 102.6  89.2 103.7  83.2 72.00
14 JB  99.60  96.2  98.2  96.2  86.2 101.7  84.5 71.34
15 JN  93.83  98.6  98.8  95.2  87.2 102.7  83.9 70.33
16 JJ  93.63 101.7  93.2  98.1   0.0   0.0  83.9 71.00
17 SJ   0.00   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 106.5  81.9 73.34
```

This is a test score that took place in some provinces of South Korea in each year.
The boundary of the test score was [0,110] until 2013, but it was changed to [0,100] in 2014.

My objective is to normalize the test score into some boundary or hopely some standardized region.

Maybe, I can first convert the scores among 2008 and 2013 into 100% scale, and subtract column mean and divide by standard deviation of each column to achieve this. But then, that is only standardized in each column.

Is there any possible way to normalize (or standardize) the test score as a whole?

By the way, the test score 0 means there was no test, so it must be ignored in the normalization process. And, this is csv format for your convenience..

```
,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015
SU,103.27,105.2,99.7,106.7,96.7,108.4,88.7,73.67
BS,100.17,104.5,97.6,103.6,91.7,106.2,85.5,73.66
DG,101,102.5,98.9,101.1,91.2,106.2,80.9,75.67
IC,97.8,103.4,97.2,102.4,88.4,103.3,85.7,70
DJ,106.2,103.1,99.1,97.7,90.7,106.2,77.5,74
GJ,97.47,101.7,98.6,101.2,89.9,105.6,81.7,73.33
US,99.8,105.6,98.2,0,81.7,103.6,84.3,68
GG,98.13,105.7,98.6,103.7,92.2,105.2,85.9,73.66
GO,96.13,101.2,96.8,101.7,86.4,105.7,78.1,72.66
CB,104.2,105.2,101.5,100.3,88.3,106.2,78.8,72
CN,107.2,95,96.1,98.7,88.2,103.7,78.5,71.33
GB,98.87,102,95.3,100.2,87.2,104.2,78.5,70.33
GN,99.57,103.3,95.6,102.6,89.2,103.7,83.2,72
JB,99.6,96.2,98.2,96.2,86.2,101.7,84.5,71.34
JN,93.83,98.6,98.8,95.2,87.2,102.7,83.9,70.33
JJ,93.63,101.7,93.2,98.1,0,0,83.9,71
SJ,0,0,0,0,0,106.5,81.9,73.34
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best would probably need be to convert columns 2 to 6 i.e. the ones in the range [0-110] to the range of [0-100]. In this way everything will be in the same scale. In order to do this:

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='    X  X2008 X2009 X2010 X2011 X2012 X2013 X2014 X2015
1  SU 103.27 105.2  99.7 106.7  96.7 108.4  88.7 73.67
2  BS 100.17 104.5  97.6 103.6  91.7 106.2  85.5 73.66
3  DG 101.00 102.5  98.9 101.1  91.2 106.2  80.9 75.67
4  IC  97.80 103.4  97.2 102.4  88.4 103.3  85.7 70.00
5  DJ 106.20 103.1  99.1  97.7  90.7 106.2  77.5 74.00
6  GJ  97.47 101.7  98.6 101.2  89.9 105.6  81.7 73.33
7  US  99.80 105.6  98.2   0.0  81.7 103.6  84.3 68.00
8  GG  98.13 105.7  98.6 103.7  92.2 105.2  85.9 73.66
9  GO  96.13 101.2  96.8 101.7  86.4 105.7  78.1 72.66
10 CB 104.20 105.2 101.5 100.3  88.3 106.2  78.8 72.00
11 CN 107.20  95.0  96.1  98.7  88.2 103.7  78.5 71.33
12 GB  98.87 102.0  95.3 100.2  87.2 104.2  78.5 70.33
13 GN  99.57 103.3  95.6 102.6  89.2 103.7  83.2 72.00
14 JB  99.60  96.2  98.2  96.2  86.2 101.7  84.5 71.34
15 JN  93.83  98.6  98.8  95.2  87.2 102.7  83.9 70.33
16 JJ  93.63 101.7  93.2  98.1   0.0   0.0  83.9 71.00
17 SJ   0.00   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 106.5  81.9 73.34')
```

You could do:

```
df[2:6] <- lapply(df[2:6], function(x) {
   x / 110 * 100 
})
```

Essentially you divide by 120 which is the max in [0-110] in order to convert to the range between [0-1] and then multiply by 100 to convert that in the range between [0-100].

Output:

```
> df
    X    X2008    X2009    X2010    X2011    X2012 X2013 X2014 X2015
1  SU 93.88182 95.63636 90.63636 97.00000 87.90909 108.4  88.7 73.67
2  BS 91.06364 95.00000 88.72727 94.18182 83.36364 106.2  85.5 73.66
3  DG 91.81818 93.18182 89.90909 91.90909 82.90909 106.2  80.9 75.67
4  IC 88.90909 94.00000 88.36364 93.09091 80.36364 103.3  85.7 70.00
5  DJ 96.54545 93.72727 90.09091 88.81818 82.45455 106.2  77.5 74.00
6  GJ 88.60909 92.45455 89.63636 92.00000 81.72727 105.6  81.7 73.33
7  US 90.72727 96.00000 89.27273  0.00000 74.27273 103.6  84.3 68.00
8  GG 89.20909 96.09091 89.63636 94.27273 83.81818 105.2  85.9 73.66
9  GO 87.39091 92.00000 88.00000 92.45455 78.54545 105.7  78.1 72.66
10 CB 94.72727 95.63636 92.27273 91.18182 80.27273 106.2  78.8 72.00
11 CN 97.45455 86.36364 87.36364 89.72727 80.18182 103.7  78.5 71.33
12 GB 89.88182 92.72727 86.63636 91.09091 79.27273 104.2  78.5 70.33
13 GN 90.51818 93.90909 86.90909 93.27273 81.09091 103.7  83.2 72.00
14 JB 90.54545 87.45455 89.27273 87.45455 78.36364 101.7  84.5 71.34
15 JN 85.30000 89.63636 89.81818 86.54545 79.27273 102.7  83.9 70.33
16 JJ 85.11818 92.45455 84.72727 89.18182  0.00000   0.0  83.9 71.00
17 SJ  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 106.5  81.9 73.34
```

And now you can compare between the years. Also, as you will notice zeros will remain zeros.

Comment: Thank you for the super fast reply. 
Do you think? if I need standardization? 
I mean subtract the whole mean and and divide by standard deviation?
Maybe, I don't need it..

Comment: As far as I understand you want to be able to compare the scores, right? The above method does exactly that. I don't see any reason to standardize. Why would you do it? Standardizing by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation is a technique used a lot in machine learning or hypothesis testing but you don't have any of those here. You just want to compare the scores. Also, each year would have a different mean and different standard deviation and using the global mean and global standard deviation would be wrong. It would also not guarantee staying in the ranges

Comment: because half of your values would be negative, as you center around zero as if your scores follow a standard normal distribution. My opinion is no do not standardize if you only want to compare scores. Having negative values would also corrupt your zero scores and make them incomprehensible.

Comment: I really think you do not need the standardization on this occasion. You are very welcome, and I am glad I was able to help :).

Comment: Also, since you are new to the site, I would suggest having a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) about how to accept an answer. Accepting an answer (by clicking the tick sign next to it) is not compulsory but is encouraged if it solves your problem. It will also give both of you and the person who answered reputation which helps you use the site better. And welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: You are right. I was confused when the scale was not the same. Maybe I don't need the standardization here to compare the score. 

But, for example, when I see the score 73.67 (SU, 2015), I am curious about what underlying effect might be related with it. The score could be a tendency of SU in a row or the deviation from the average score in year 2015 of the column, or both. So.. what method would be appropriate to dig into this underlying effect? May be the 2-way ANOVA(but the linear assumption was to primitive so...)? Could you give me any advice? :) p.s. Thank you for welcoming and advice.!

Comment: It is very hard to tell what method would be appropriate, without having much context about the data. There are lots of hypothesis tests but you need to have the appropriate data to test. If you are really looking for a method to use about testing something, maybe you could ask in stats.stackexchange.com where they would give you advice about which potential method you could use. My advice is to give as much insight about your data as you can and please always consider whether you really need a statistical model for understanding your data. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok. One naive approach I'm considering right now is converting the test score into the ratio by deviding the test score by the maximum test score at each year. This could probably remove the effect of difficuilty of the test in each year.. At least.. And I guess I need to think more about it.. Haha.. Thank you!